# Microsoft Access - Preview Report Which The Date Field is same as the text field date

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, report

how to preview the report in Microsoft Access with a button in a form?
Currently, I have the VBA code like this:

```
Private Sub ThisReceiptBtn_Click()
DoCmd.OpenReport "Picking_PackingReceipt", acPreview, , _
"PickingDate = Today()"
End Sub
```

but, it is not working for showing the report on today's date.

Another button is used to preview the report where the date is the same date as the date field in the form.
the code is like this:

```
Private Sub ThisReceiptBtn_Click()
    
    If IsNull(Me!txtPickID) Then
    MsgBox "Please select a valid record", _
    vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Picking_PackingReceipt", acPreview, , _
    "PickingDate =" & Me! TxtDate
    
End Sub
```

but it also didn't work. please help.

Comment: If you want to filter report by a date in data, then do that. If you want to show today's date on report as date of print, then do that. It is not clear what you want.

Comment: Hi, sorry for that. I have edited my questions. Could you help me?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Should include that info in your question. There are two buttons with same name so there are two forms?

Answer (score 0):

`Today()` is not a valid function in VBA. Use `Date()`.

For the second version, try:
`"PickingDate = #" & Me.TxtDate & "#"`